# Exercise 1-20 of the book "C - The Programming Language 2nd Edition"

Tags: c, replace, tabs, space

Currently I'm reading the book "C - The Programming Language" and I have a questions to this exercise:

"Write a program 'detab' that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number of blanks to space to the next tab stop. Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every n-colmuns. Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?"

Let aside the question in the exercise I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLUMNS 5   /* number of columns for a tab */

int main()
{
    char c;
int i;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\t') {
        for (i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++)
            putchar(' ');
    }
    else
        putchar(c);
}

return 0;
}
```

Then I checked Online for solutions and found this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER   1024
#define SPACE        ' '
#define TAB          '\t'

int CalculateNumberOfSpaces(int Offset, int TabSize)
{
   return TabSize - (Offset % TabSize);
}

/* K&R's getline() function from p29 */
int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i;

  for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
    s[i] = c;
  if(c == '\n')
  {
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}

int main(void)
{
  char  Buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
  int TabSize = 5; /* A good test value */

  int i, j, k, l;

  while(getline(Buffer, MAX_BUFFER) > 0)
  {
    for(i = 0, l = 0; Buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
      if(Buffer[i] == TAB)
      {
        j = CalculateNumberOfSpaces(l, TabSize);
        for(k = 0; k < j; k++)
        {
          putchar(SPACE);
          l++;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        putchar(Buffer[i]);
        l++;
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My question now is what the difference between my code an the other code is.
I thought the exercise would ask that each \t that occurs should be replaced by n spaces.

Now I don't what the other code does.

Maybe I understood the exercise wrong. If so please explain it to me.

Thanks for your help.

---

Ok so how about this solution:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8   /* size of a tab */

int main()
{
char c;
int i,column = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\t') {
        for (i = column; i < TAB; i++){
            putchar(' ');
        }
        column = -1;
    }
    else{
        putchar(c);
        }
    column++;
}

return 0;
}
```

New Version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAB 8   /* size of a tab */

int main()
{
char c;
int i,column = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if(c == '\n')
        column = -1;

    if(column >= TAB)
        column = 0;

    if (c == '\t') {
        for (i = column; i < TAB; i++){
            putchar(' ');
        }
        column = -1;
    }
    else{
        putchar(c);
        }
    column++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: number of spaces to tab stop will vary depending on the location tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to replace every tab by the same number of spaces: some will be replaced by less than that.

Imagine we want TAB to 10 spaces

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
one<TAB>  two<TAB>  fortytwo  four
   ^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^        ^^
   7 space   7 space        2
```

Comment: Your last code fails with input like `Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis<TAB>foobar`

Comment: Now I think I got it. "column" was sometimes not right. And it works with Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis<TAB>foobar

Comment: @pmg Late question: but how would the input and output look different? Also, the output should be displayed per line, or should it be displayed after user has finished entering the whole input?

Answer (score 8):

You got it wrong. You have to replace each tab by spaces until the next tab stop. That depends exactly on where the cursor is.

So, if there's a tab stop every 5 columns, and you can think of it like:

```
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
```

Where `|` is a tab stop and `-` is a character. Hitting a tab takes you to the next tab stop. So, for example, if you write 3 characters from the beginning of the previous tab stop, and then hit tab, you only have to write 2 spaces.

Comment: I didn't manage to do it in the comments, so I put my edited new code in my question. Would be nice if you have a look at it.